# How to insert a column in a gridview after the auto generated columns - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TestColumn">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lkbtn" runat="server" Text="Edit"
                    CommandName="Update" CausesValidation="False" ToolTip="Edit" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The **TestColumn** ends up being the first column, but i want it after the auto generated ones.

Comment: Can you use jQuery to change columns position ?

Answer (score 3):

In the `RowDataBound` event handler, you can move the TemplateField cell from the first column to the end of the row:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[0];
    e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(0);
    e.Row.Cells.Add(cell);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it may not be possible. Read [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx):

> You can also combine explicitly declared column fields with
>   automatically generated column fields. When both are used, explicitly
>   declared column fields are rendered first, followed by the
>   automatically generated column fields. Automatically generated bound
>   column fields are not added to the Columns collection.

Answer (score -1):

You set the AutoGenerateColumnProperty to false, and then you order your columns as you like.

If you just want to add an edit button, you should use:

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
```

Here is an example using the northwind database

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
DataKeyNames="ProductID"
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID"
InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductID" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="SupplierID" HeaderText="SupplierID" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="QuantityPerUnit" HeaderText="QuantityPerUnit"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="UnitPrice" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="UnitsInStock" HeaderText="UnitsInStock" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="UnitsOnOrder" HeaderText="UnitsOnOrder" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="ReorderLevel" HeaderText="ReorderLevel" />
<asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Discontinued" HeaderText="Discontinued"/>
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: The OP clearly specified that he/she wants the columns to be auto-generated. Using your way will take out that advantage of auto-generating columns.